# how to send/inject packet into local network interface (linux)

Tags: linux, sockets

I am working on a C program on Linux (kernel 2.6.18). I need to send/inject IP packets (e.g., over a socket) in my Linux systems, but make the same Linux "think" that these packets are incoming from another host. I creat a datalink socket and use faked source mac/ip for the packets sent over this socket. The destination mac/ip are set to the ones in my local Linux. However, whether I send these packets in a user-space program or in a kernel module, my local Linux just doesn't think these packets are coming from outside. For example, if I create a datalink socket to send an ICMP request destined to my local Linux, I expect my local Linux to think this ICMP request coming from outside, and would respond with an ICMP reply, but my local Linux does not do so. (However, with the same program I can send a faked ICMP request to another host, and that host does respond an ICMP reply.)

I did some research on this topic online, and it seems all related solution suggest using TAP. But as [this VirtualBox article](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html) says:

> ... TAP is no longer necessary on Linux with bridged networking, ...

I am very interested to know how this is possible. Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Will modifying  your program to use the loopback interface do what you need? Trying to send something to yourself via eth0 won't work.

Comment: @ChrisRyding: "Trying to send something to yourself via eth0 won't work." This is what I want to accomplish. It appears to me Vmware and VirtualBox somehow accomplish this task. If a guest virtual OS sends packets to the host, you can use WireShark to see the packets on eth0 of the host. And to the host, it "thinks" the packets coming form the wire connected to eth0.

Comment: Virtual machines set up virtual interfaces in the kernel and play games with the packets going in and out. You will either need to set up a pair of VM's or install kernel drivers that handle that same functionality. Unfortunately I don't have the expertise in that particular area but it does seem like TAP is the right path. As I recall, network bridging is creating a transparent path between two external paths. You want an internal path.